# target pattern contains no '%'

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I tried to build the ndk and get error

**/android-ndk-r9/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:68: ***** **target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.******

my Android.mk code is :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES := on 
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES := on
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

include D:/Books/Java/winx86_01Jan12/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := F_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := f

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

please help Until I resolve my problem.I'm really confused.I tried several ways and I could not solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ndk-build` invokes `make` which does not handle the **:** character in targets well. If your project resides on disk D:, too, then you can refer to OpenCV without the drive letter,

```
include /Books/Java/winx86_01Jan12/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

Otherwise you can try

```
include //D/Books/Java/winx86_01Jan12/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
include //localhost/D$/Books/Java/winx86_01Jan12/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

If nothing helps, copy your OpenCV SDK such that you can use a relative path, e.g.

```
include ../../OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

**PS** The source of your troubles is probably *cygwin* somewhere on the PATH. Since November 2011, NDK r7, `ndk-build` does not need *cygwin*. **OpenCV** made the reciprocate step short afterwards. Unfortunately, many developers still need *cygwin* for their daily work; furthermore, until recently, you still needed *cygwin* to run **ndk-dgb** (you have **`ndk-gdb-py.cmd`** now!). So my advice is to remove `cygwin\bin` directory from your PATH before you run **`ndk-build.cmd`**. You can easily do it in Project build properties if you use Ecliplse/ADT to build your native code.

Comment: My project  resides on disk "D:". I use Three your methods. two method first not work. But I Copy "OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk" file in relative path and use "../../OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk" and work. thank you.